# Converting binary to base 4

Tags: vb.net, string, binary, numbers, radix

**What I hope to achieve:**

I want to convert text to DNA (which is a base 4 system, "a,G,T,c")

**How I plan to do it:**

Convert text string to binary,

```
        Dim BinaryConvert As String = ""
        For Each C As Char In Textbox1.Text
            Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
            BinaryConvert &= s
        Next
        Textbox1.Text = BinaryConvert '//Changes the textbox1.Text into binary form
```

Then convert binary to base 4 via Pseudocode solution:

*if (length of binary String is an odd number) add a zero to the front (leftmost position) of the String.
Create an empty String to add translated digits to.
While the original String of binary is not empty {
Translate the first two digits only of the binary String into a base-4 digit, and add this digit to the end (rightmost) index of the new String.
After this, remove the same two digits from the binary string and repeat if it is not empty.
}*

The idea behind converting binary to DNA is simply setting **G** and **T** equal to one, with **c** and **a** equal to zero (G=T=1, a=c=0).

So all I have to do is convert the string to binary first, and then into base 4, in order to convert text to genetic code. Could you please help me write the code to convert binary to base 4.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Converting to base 4 from base 2 is pretty simple.  Since 4 itself is the 2nd power of 2, this means you can simply combine two bits to create one base 4 place (2 bits can represent 4 possible values, while 1 base 4 place can also represent 4 possible values).  For example:

11100100 (base 2) = 3210 (base 4)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Instead of 0123, can I make it aTGc ?

Comment: I am still a little bit confused as to how you have base 4 if you assign GT=1 and ac=0.  It seems to me that you would need to assign each letter a 2 bit value rather than a 1 bit value. Such as a=00, c=01, G=10, T=11.

Comment: It is not GT=1 and ac=0 but rather G=T=1 and a=c=0

Comment: Would this work?
Pseudocode solution:
if (length of binary String is an odd number) add a zero to the front (leftmost position) of the String.
Create an empty String to add translated digits to.
While the original String of binary is not empty {
Translate the first two digits only of the binary String into a base-4 digit, and add this digit to the end (rightmost) index of the new String.
After this, remove the same two digits from the binary string and repeat if it is not empty.
}

Comment: Your pseudocode seems like a solid solution for converting from binary to base 4 to me.  Now it's all a matter of implementation.